# Need help decompiling .img file to theme UI

Tags: linux

Sorry if it's been asked before but I have this aftermarket digital cluster in my jeep and it runs some kind of Linux version in it. I was wondering if I could get some help in decompiling the update.img so I can change the color of the jeep on there (see link below). I'm a complete noob with linux but I'm really hoping someone can help me out and I'm ready to learn. Thanks in advance!!

https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjT3Yr76N_lAhWKb30KHQ4VDywQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpikdo.net%2Fp%2Fcarobotor%2F2112760189884553998_10352179187&psig=AOvVaw1NUiAGjpumblfTOppJ3T-a&ust=1573481339573105

---

```
> fdisk -l "sun8iw11p1_linux_t3-p3_uart0.img"
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

> file "sun8iw11p1_linux_t3-p3_uart0.img"
sun8iw11p1_linux_t3-p3_uart0.img: data
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out what the img is first;

```
fdisk -l "$IMG"
file "$IMG"
xxd "$IMG" | head
```

Provide a link to the img.

Update;
Because file said "data" you need reverse engineering time and skills to figure out how to translate the data into something meaningful (what the requested and not provided xxd and link to img are for). So I recommend you file this goal/question under unachievable for now.

Comment: Sorry for being ignorant but instead of "$img" do I put the img file name? Also I'm happy to donate if anyone can help me haha

Comment: Ok so I've ran your commands and it came back with saying that the .img file has 328772608 bytes and 642134 sectors at 512 bytes

sun8iw11p1_linux_t3-p3_uart0.img: data

and the third command came back with what looks like hex codes?

Comment: I've attached a .txt file below

Comment: ;Disk sun8iw11p1_linux_t3-p3_uart0.img: 313.6 MiB, 328772608 bytes, 642134 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
mcmethylated@mcmethylated-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/JEEP_UPDATE_FILE0801$ file "sun8iw11p1_linux_t3-p3_uart0.img"
sun8iw11p1_linux_t3-p3_uart0.img: data

Comment: I try to mount the image now after a better understanding of how it works but I'm getting "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop18, missing codepage or helper program, or other error." If I sent you the .img file could you help me sort it out ? I'm happy to pay you if it works out! :)